# RTMP sink for Microsoft Media Foundation

Tags: flash, streaming, rtmp, ms-media-foundation

I'm new to Microsoft Media Foundation and I want to enable my application to support live streaming via Flash Media Streaming Server. I was searching for third party MFTs for Media Foundation but unfortunately I wasn't able to find any companies that offer MFTs. To be more precise I need an RTMP sink MFT. Do you know any good third party RTMP sinks (commercial or free) or do I have to stick with DirectShow?

Comment: Well, since no one is answering: Does anyone know a vendor of commercial Media Foundation Transforms, sources or sinks?